Does my code follow DDD principles?
I apologize in advance for my English.
I'm trying to model P2P crypto trading using DDD and I'm having trouble modeling the lifecycle of sell orders. Lifecycle:

Some trader-seller creates an order.
Some trader-buyer responds to it.
Buyer confirms the transfer of fiat to the seller's account.
Seller confirms the receipt of fiat from the buyer to his account.

As a result, I got the following C# code:
SellOrder.cs:
public class SellOrder
{
    public SellOrder(Guid guid, SellOrderInfo info, Guid sellerGuid, string sellerToExchangerTransferTransactionHash)
    {
        if (!ValidateSellOrderInfo(info))
            throw new InvariantViolationException("Info is invalid.");
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sellerToExchangerTransferTransactionHash))
            throw new DevelopmentErrorException("Seller to exchanger transfer transaction hash is invalid.");
        
        Status = SellOrderStatus.Created;

        SellerGuid = sellerGuid;
        SellerToExchangerTransferTransactionHash = sellerToExchangerTransferTransactionHash;

        BuyerGuid = null;
        BuyerWalletAddress = null;
    }
    
    private bool ValidateSellOrderInfo(SellOrderInfo info)
    {
        // Something
    }

    public void Respond(Guid buyerGuid, string buyerWalletAddress)
    {
        if (Status != SellOrderStatus.Created)
            throw new InvariantViolationException("Status is invalid.");
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(buyerWalletAddress))
            throw new DevelopmentErrorException("Buyer wallet address is invalid.");

        BuyerGuid = buyerGuid;
        BuyerWalletAddress = buyerWalletAddress;
        Status = SellOrderStatus.BuyerResponded;
    }

    public void Confirm(Guid traderGuid)
    {
        Status = Status switch
        {
            SellOrderStatus.BuyerResponded when traderGuid.Equals(BuyerGuid) => SellOrderStatus.BuyerConfirmed,
            SellOrderStatus.BuyerResponded => throw new InvariantViolationException("Trader is not a buyer."),
            SellOrderStatus.BuyerConfirmed when traderGuid.Equals(SellerGuid) => SellOrderStatus.BuyerAndSellerConfirmed,
            SellOrderStatus.BuyerConfirmed => throw new InvariantViolationException("Trader is not a seller."),
            _ => throw new InvariantViolationException("Status is invalid.")
        };
    }
    
    public SellOrderStatus Status { get; }
    
    public Guid Guid { get; }
    
    public SellOrderInfo Info { get; }

    public Guid SellerGuid { get; }

    public string SellerToExchangerTransferTransactionHash { get; }

    public Guid? BuyerGuid { get; private set; }

    public string? BuyerWalletAddress { get; private set; }
}

As I understand it, the Trader and SellOrder entities are separate aggregation roots. In the SellOrder class, I initially stored references directly to the Trader class objects, but then I learned that aggregation roots should not reference each other directly, and replaced the objects with identifiers. Did I do the right thing?
I also have a question about the void Confirm(Guid traderGuid) method: does it violate any DDD principles that I check the trader on whose behalf this method is called? Maybe it would be better to move this check to the application layer or to some domain layer service?
I also plan to add a dispute system - if the seller does not confirm receipt of the fiat, a dispute should be automatically created referencing this order. What is the best way to implement this? I think domain events would be the perfect solution here.
Thank you all in advance for participating in the discussion.

Perhaps https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ would be a better fit for this question.

DDD doesn't have a lot of hard principles

but then I learned that aggregation roots should not reference each
other directly, and replaced the objects with identifiers. Did I do
the right thing?

Yes this seems right.

Confirm(Guid traderGuid) method: does it violate any DDD principles
that I check the trader on whose behalf this method is called?

You aren't calling out to another AR, so I think this is fine. I can see that the logic could get more complex though, if you have to get the actual seller or buyer objects back then I would consider moving the logic out of a domain object and into a cross domain service.

if the seller does not confirm receipt of the fiat, a dispute should
be automatically created referencing this order. What is the best way
to implement this? I think domain events would be the perfect solution
here.

Hmmm I think this depends on whether your system as a whole is event driven or not. Throwing in just one event driven part is going to add complexity that you don't need.
